# Call WCF service with XML

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to call a WCF service.

However, I have the request body as an XML document.

So for instance, instead of this

```
ListProductsRequest request = new ListProductsRequest();
request.Query = new RootQuery();
request.Query.Product = "milk";
request.Query.Group = "dairy";

ListProductsPortType client = new ListProductsPortTypeClient();
ListProductsResponse response = client.ListProducts(request);
```

I wanna do this:

```
String xml = "<Root xmlns=\"urn:ns\"><Query><Group>dairy</Group><Product>milk</Product></Query></Root>";
var request = // read in to XmlReader or XmlDocument or whatever
ListProductsPortType client = new ListProductsPortTypeClient();
var response = client.ListProducts(request);
```

Is there a way to use the generated proxy, with the advantage of having the data layer security and transport handled for me, but without using the proxy objects?

Thanks,
Brecht

Comment: Is this a REST service? If so, then you can use a WebClient directly.

Comment: No, it's a SOAP service over NetTCP secured with SPNego etc. Too complicated to do manually.

I do a similar thing to what I want using Axis2 service client, but unfortunately Axis2 does not support SPNego, so I'm trying to create something generic in .NET to call WCF services to avoid interoperability problems.

edit: more explanation + typos

Comment: i was searching for a way to solve your problem and found this : 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/ad917cdd-60d4-404c-a529-10597ff1bbf8/
this could be a solution... using the Message and passing it to a channel let you  
choose how to format the message. 
here there is a example of Message.Create
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/7893/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can call a WCF service and passing what you want.

The method ListProducts only accept a ListProductsRequest object. So you have to create this kind of object.

```
String xml = "<Root xmlns=\"urn:ns\"><Query><Group>dairy</Group><Product>milk</Product></Query></Root>";
ListProductsRequest request = MappingObject(xml); 
ListProductsPortType client = new ListProductsPortTypeClient();
var response = client.ListProducts(request);
```

And in the Mapping method you can work with your XML to create an ListproductRequest.

I don't know if there is another way to do this.

Comment: It's not really 'what I want', the xml coming in corresponds 100% to the message contract in the wsdl.

Answer (score 1):

I got this far, thanks to 2GDev's comment. Code without handling exceptions or abnormal situations properly.

This way I can use the generated stub's endpoint (and thus reuse the config etc.)

```
    public void CallWs()
    {
        WsdlRDListProductsPortTypeClient client = new WsdlRDListProductsPortTypeClient();

        String req = "<Root xmlns=\"urn:ns\"><Query><Group>TV</Group><Product>TV</Product></Query></Root>";

        CallWs(client.Endpoint, "ListProducts", GetRequestXml(req));
    }

    public XmlElement CallWs(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, String operation, XmlElement request)
    {
        String soapAction = GetSoapAction(endpoint, operation);

        IChannelFactory<IRequestChannel> factory = null;

        try
        {
            factory = endpoint.Binding.BuildChannelFactory<IRequestChannel>();
            factory.Open();
            IRequestChannel channel = null;

            try
            {
                channel = factory.CreateChannel(endpoint.Address);
                channel.Open();

                Message requestMsg = Message.CreateMessage(endpoint.Binding.MessageVersion, soapAction, request);
                Message response = channel.Request(requestMsg);
                return response.GetBody<XmlElement>();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (channel != null)
                    channel.Close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (factory != null)
                factory.Close();
        }
    }

    private String GetSoapAction(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, String operation)
    {

        foreach (OperationDescription opD in endpoint.Contract.Operations)
        {
            if (opD.Name == operation)
            {
                foreach (MessageDescription msgD in opD.Messages)
                    if (msgD.Direction == MessageDirection.Input)
                    {
                        return msgD.Action;
                    }
            }

        }

        return null;
    }
```

When I try this with the basic ICalculator sample from msdn
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx

Which is secured with SPNego, I have to change this a bit, because then we need an IRequestSessionChannel instead of an IRequestChannel.

```
    public XmlElement CallWs(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, String operation, XmlElement request)
    {
        String soapAction = GetSoapAction(endpoint, operation);

        IChannelFactory<IRequestSessionChannel> factory = null;

        try
        {


            factory = endpoint.Binding.BuildChannelFactory<IRequestSessionChannel>();
            factory.Open();
            IRequestSessionChannel channel = null;

            try
            {
                channel = factory.CreateChannel(endpoint.Address);
                channel.Open();

                Message requestMsg = Message.CreateMessage(endpoint.Binding.MessageVersion, soapAction, request);

                Message response = channel.Request(requestMsg);
                return response.GetBody<XmlElement>();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (channel != null)
                    channel.Close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (factory != null)
                factory.Close();
        }
    }
```

It does do the negotiation, and a message seems to be sent, but unfortunately I now get the following error message:

```
No signature message parts were specified for messages with the 'http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples/ICalculator/Add' action.
```

Comment: In the end I just went with deserializing the xml to the proxy objects using http://wcfpro.wordpress.com/2010/11/24/customxmlobjectserializer/ and using those.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use

```
ListProductsRequest request = (ListProductsRequest) new XmlSerializer(
    typeof(ListProductsRequest)).Deserialize();
```

to create the corresponding object...

Comment: Thanks. The problem with this is that I get the XML from somewhere else, and I want this to be generic. The deserialize method tells me there is a problem with the XML document (that 'Root' was not expected), though I can read it in as plain xml.

I suspect the reason for this is that ListProductsRequest has an Attribute specifying the Wrapper element name, and that this is not expected by the XmlSerializer.

[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="Root", WrapperNamespace="urn:ns", IsWrapped=true)]

Comment: Using this blog post I was able to deserialize the request. http://wcfpro.wordpress.com/2010/11/24/customxmlobjectserializer/